# Where is the source code of opensource titanium developer hiding?

Tags: javascript, iphone, c, open-source

Titanium pretends to be opensource but it isn't obvious where it can be downloaded.

Comment: does open source products have a how to buy page? http://www.appcelerator.com/company/how-to-buy/ :)

Comment: @naveen: https://www.redhat.com/wapps/store/catalog.html

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/3931/building-titanium-from-source

it's shown right there. Took me 5 mins to find.

Comment: Why it isn't on download page ? I suspect that in some future they will change license to closed.

Comment: That site looks... familiar...

Comment: @user310291 It's not on their download page because it's not supposed to be downloaded by average users/developers. It is however fully accessible through their official GitHub repository.